# PineScript: make the script look for the value if it was true in the last x bars

Tags: tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I have a value I set and want the script to look if it was true in the last lets say 10 bars. I know I can use [] 10 times which would give the same result, but it doesn't look right. Is there a code to add to make the script look for the last x bars with one code?

Answer (score 1):

Just convert it to 1 or 0 and then get the highest for the last X bars:

```
check_condition = ...
condition_true_last_x_bars = ta.highest(check_condition ? 1 : 0, x_bars) > 0
```